# disappear MenuButton UISplitView on landscape orientation iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm developing an app for iOS with Xcode

using a UISplitViewController I want to hide menú button when I set orientation on landscape, I could make it with my MasterVC (menu), this is the code so far

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc{

    //Grab a reference to the popover
    _popover            = pc;

    barButtonItem.title = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FABars];
    [barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:TOOLBARICONTEXTATTRIBUTES forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    UINavigationItem *navItem       = self.navigationItem;
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
 invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem{


    //Remove the barButtonItem.
    [_navBarItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];

    //Nil out the pointer to the popover.
    _popover = nil;

}



-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }

}
```

on portrait mode looks good

[image]

on landscape mode, menu button still remains
[image]

but in landscape if I press touch menu button, masterVC (view controller with menu) reappears like in portrait mode
[image]

and then when I touch on detailVC, my masterVC dissapears and left my view ugly
[image]

how to hide that button on landscape mode for disabling such button action